# wash sale for short-term loss?

Tags: united-states, wash-sale

Let's say I buy 1 share of stock X for $2, then sell that share back a week later for $1.

The wash sale rules say that it's a wash sale if I buy the stock within 30 days before or after the sale.   Does this transaction count as a wash sale?  I would guess not, but I couldn't find any online guidance on this point.  Maybe because experts consider it too obvious? :)

I have read that if I then buy the stock back soon after it'll be a wash sale.  I understand that.  But in this case I'm just selling it and using the money for something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wash sale is a transaction where you discard shares at a loss only to repurchase it again. The IRS wants to prevent tax loss harvesting without substantial change of the underlying holding.

Since in your scenario there's no repurchase - there's no wash sale. Just a sale.

Comment: How does this square with the language that you can't buy a security 30 days "before" the wash sale?

Comment: @KevinBurke in the OPs scenario the share bought is the share sold.